# Can not access <input type="button"> of a master page from a content page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an

```html
<input type="button" id="Button1">
```

in my `Master1.master` masterpage. (that resides in a `<div>`).

I also have a content page `Main.aspx`.
I want to set the visibility of the button to `true` when I access the content page `Main.aspx`, for example, from another page. (I have a `Login.aspx` page, and after I insert user/psw and press a button I ged redirected to `Main.aspx`).

I have added the directive `<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Master1.master" %>`
and i am using the following code

```
Button home = new Button();
home = (Button)Master.FindControl("Button1");
home.Visible = false;
```

However I get a `NullReferenceException` when i try to run this.
So basically I can't see the "Button1".
I have tried to change the values to `head` or `ContentHolder1` and with these it runs perfectly.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access input which is not a server side control :

Youll need :

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `runat` attribute:

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the master page expose a property that you can then use to reference the `Button`.  The ID of the control is going to be changed during the render event;  that is why you cannot find it.  Using the property on the master page, you can then address the control by accessing the `Page.Master` variable.  You will need to cast it into the master page class so that you can use IntelliSense to access the public and friend methods/properties.  Here is some code ... sorry it is in VB.

Here is the master page HTML.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button1" runat="server" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the master page code-behind.

```
Partial Class MasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Public ReadOnly Property Button As Control
        Get
            Return button1
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Here is the content page.

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CType(Page.Master, MasterPage).Button.Text = "My Text"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Notice the rendered control name below; they are not what you expect.  You can get the real rendered name from the UniqueID property.